# Detect Flash Block for Website

Tags: flash, flash-block

I have a flash blocker installed on my browser. On certain sites, such as soundcloud.com, when I go there I get a notification that I must enable flash for it to work correctly.

How do I achieve the same functionality on my website?

In other words how do I detect if a flash block program is enabled?

I prefer *client side* code only if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) & [call](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) a javascript function to let the page know whether flash is blocked or not.

Something as simple as:

**AS3:**

```
ExternalInterface.call("flashLoaded");
```

& in **JS**:

```
function flashLoaded() {

   // Flash was not blocked, since you are here.

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? That page is a bit confusing.